# drive.install - what is a use case for this scope?

Tags: google-drive-api, google-oauth, google-apps-marketplace

Looking at [Google Drive scopes](https://developers.google.com/drive/web/scopes). I see:

`https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.install` - Special scope used to let users approve installation of an app

Do I specify this scope if I want my application be install-able by user from Marketplace? What is a use case for this scope?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its not specifically for Marketplace apps. Its for being able to ask users for permission to install your app in their Drive (from anywhere, your website, etc).
ask users for permission to install your app in their Drive.

See more here:
http://googleappsdeveloper.blogspot.com/2012/09/announcing-google-drive-installation.html

Comment: So I must include this scope if I want to install (integrate) my app into user's Google Drive?  If I just include `drive.file` scope, I will be able to create/open files but the app wont be installed?

Comment: Its all in the linked article and documentation. But basically yes.