# Google OAuth2 implicit flow second call to requestAccessToken never resolved

Tags: javascript, google-drive-api, google-oauth

I want to connect from a browser to Google Drive by OAuth2 with two scopes:

- `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive` - necessary
- `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.install` - optional.

When I use both scopes in `google.accounts.oauth2.initTokenClient` and a user confirms just the necessary scope and reloads the page (or token expires), then the user is bothered with a window to confirm the optional scope. So, I have tried to do two calls: the first one with no prompt and necessary scope only, if it fails, then the second one with both scopes:

```js
let tokenResponse = await new Promise(resolve => {
    google.accounts.oauth2.initTokenClient({
        client_id: clientId,
        scope: scope1,
        prompt: "none", // never show a popup
        callback: resolve
    }).requestAccessToken();
});
if (tokenResponse.error && tokenResponse.error === "interaction_required") {
    tokenResponse = await new Promise(resolve => {
        google.accounts.oauth2.initTokenClient({
            client_id: clientId,
            scope: scope1 + " " + scope2,
            prompt: undefined, // show popup
            callback: resolve
       }).requestAccessToken();
    });
}
```

However, the second call never returns (even when I have pop-ups explicitly allowed). How is possible to handle optional scopes or two calls to `requestAccessToken()`?

Comment: https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.install  <-- is that even a valid scope?   [Google drive api scopes](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/scopes#drive)

Comment: @DalmTo see https://developers.google.com/drive/api/guides/api-specific-auth or this SO question [drive.install - what is a use case for this scope?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22182252/)

Comment: wow nice havent seen that one before